# Align labels of a custom UITableViewCell when editing

Tags: ios, uitableview, alignment, label

I have an UITableView with several prototype cells and some of the editable cells are basic cells and some customs. 
(XCode 4.6.1 / iOS 6.1)

My question is how to automatically align the labels of the custom cells (in the Storyboard) like it's done by default for basic cells' *textLabel*?

Here's two screenshots to understand what I mean:
[image: Before edit mode]
[image: In edit mode]

By the way, I've obviously Google'd before and didn't find anything but maybe I missed something, as I'm a newbie on iOS :)

**Edit:** you probably already understood the screens, but in case of: the "add" cell is a default basic cell and the "delete" cells are custom cells with my own UILabel (with the wrong alignment).

Comment: You are familiar with `layoutSubviews` but want to do it at storyboard ?

Comment: Well, I just care about being able to design prototype cells content in the storyboard, as I will have more complex designs in the future. If I have to add some code it's ok though.

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/742829/animating-custom-drawn-uitableviewcell-when-entering-edit-mode).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was so complicated for a so easy-looking stuff :)

Comment: But it works really nice with not so much code, doesn't it ? Please make sure to describe your final solution at the answer and accept it, it will help somebody in the future.

Comment: I will as soon as I succeed, for now the code compiles but nothing happens.

Comment: If you post some code that will help us to find out why it's not working.