# iOS 7: UITableViewController: Changing/Replacing Delete Button

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios7

*Disclaimer: I know it's not a best practice to tweak that kind of stuff because it may break as Apple decides to change its internal behaviour.*

There are some solutions out there like https://stackoverflow.com/a/12511432/271150 which seem to be working for previous iOS versions, but not for iOS 7.

When looking into the controls hierarchy I can see there is a UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView inside the UITableViewCellScrollView. But by looking into the SubViews collection in layoutSubviews or willTransitionToState there are only my own views, UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationView does not appear.

[image]

So, has anyone figured out how to modify the default delete button/view?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254402/swipe-to-delete-and-the-more-button-like-in-mail-app-on-ios-7

Comment: Nope. And it's not answered correctly either.

Comment: There is no correct answer to "how to tweak a UI hierarchy you're not supposed to tweak" - it'll always be a hack. The 2nd and 3rd answer seems quite like a valid approach.

Comment: The question really is: do you want a DELETE button? Then keep the default behavior. Do you want something else? Then implement your own UITableViewCell and add a gesture recognizer to hide/show YOUR buttons.

Comment: I use a red tintColor in my app that seriously conflicts with the orange-red used by the delete button's background color, it would be really ideal to set it to the same UIColor as my tintColor, I think adding my own gesture recognizer for that is a bit overkill. Be nice if we could modify it directly for edge cases like that, it's a good question.

Answer (score 4):

I understand you may not want to overwrite Apples entire implementation for editing a table view cell BUT I had a similar problem with my app. In my case I needed two buttons (More and Lost) to display just like in the new reminders app for iOS7 when a user swipes left to right. Instead of using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I created a custom cell that hides the buttons under the top layer and uses a pan gesture recogniser to move the top layer, displaying the buttons underneath. I therefore have complete control over what buttons are displayed and what color etc they are (see below).

```
static CGFloat const kEditButtonWidth = 82.0;

@interface MyCustomCell ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat firstX;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat firstY;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *topLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *moreButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *lostButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *titleLabel;
@end

@implementation MyCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        // BOTTOM LAYER (MORE AND LOST BUTTONS)
        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [aButton setFrame:CGRectZero];
        [aButton setTitle:@"More" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.78 green:0.78 blue:0.78 alpha:1.0]];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:aButton];
        [self setMoreButton:aButton];

        aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [aButton setFrame:CGRectZero];
        [aButton setTitle:@"Lost" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setTitleShadowColor:[UIColor clearColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.00f green:0.23f blue:0.19f alpha:1.00f]];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:aButton];
        [self setLostButton:aButton];

        // TOP LAYER
        UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [aView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:aView];
        [self setTopLayer:aView];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *aPanRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureAction:)];
        [aPanRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [aPanRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
        [aView addGestureRecognizer:aPanRecognizer];

        // title label
        UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [aView addSubview:aLabel];
        [self setTitleLabel:aLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect bounds = [[self contentView] bounds];
    CGRect frame = CGRectZero;

    // BOTTOM LAYER (MORE AND LOST BUTTONS)
    frame.origin.x = bounds.size.width-(kEditButtonWidth+kEditButtonWidth); // two buttons wide
    frame.size.width = kEditButtonWidth;
    frame.size.height = bounds.size.height;
    [[self moreButton] setFrame:frame];

    frame.origin.x += kEditButtonWidth;
    [[self lostButton] setFrame:frame];

    // TOP LAYER
    frame = bounds;
    CGPoint anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, [[[self topLayer] layer] anchorPoint].y);
    [[[self topLayer] layer] setAnchorPoint:anchorPoint];
    [[self topLayer] setFrame:frame];

    // title label
    frame.origin.x = 20.0;
    frame.origin.y = 4.0;
    frame.size.width = bounds.size.width-40.0;
    frame.size.height = 21.0;
    [[self titleLabel] setFrame:frame];
}

- (void)panGestureAction:(id)sender {

    // on the first touch, get the center coordinates (x and y) of the view
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self];
    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        [self setFirstX:[[sender view] center].x];
        [self setFirstY:[[sender view] center].y];
    }

    // add translated point to reference points
    translatedPoint = CGPointMake([self firstX]+translatedPoint.x, [self firstY]);
    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

    // when pan ends (set final x to be either back to zero or showing buttons)
    if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x+(0.30*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self].x);
        if (finalX < -1.0f*FMEditButtonWidth) {
            finalX = -2.0f*FMEditButtonWidth;
            [self setEditMode:YES];
        } else {
            finalX = 0.0f;
            [self setEditMode:NO];
        }

        // animate view
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0f initialSpringVelocity:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
            [[sender view] setCenter:CGPointMake(finalX, [self firstY])];
        } completion:NULL];
    }
}

@end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I will give it a try in the next weeks.

Comment: i tried the code, but i can not figure out, why the gesture is not recognized. the method does not get called. can you help here?

Comment: @alexdd55 set a break-point in initWithStyle: to see that it's firing and hooking up your gesture correctly.

Comment: how do you detect when to hide the more and lost buttons?  I cant figure out how to make it so you can only slide one cell at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the view inside `layoutSubviews` or `willTransitionToState:` is that the delete button view does not exist yet or it is not part of the view hierarchy yet.
In order to "see" it you need to postpone a little the code that browses the view hierarchy,  and by that allowing the OS to create/add the view in the meantime:

```
- (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)state
{
    [super willTransitionToState:state];

    if (state & UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(findDeleteButtonViewThroughViewHierarchy:) withObject:self.subviews afterDelay:0];
    }
}
```

Note this is a fragile solution since it is based on internal implementation of Apple that might change any time.

See here an (almost) complete example:

[Customizing iOS 7 Delete button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412487/1298263)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this works on ios 7 but take a look:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)

   {

    //   Your Code

    }
}
```

Comment: This method is getting called when clicking the button, so it's to late - but thanks ;-).