# How to handle UITableViewCell delete button animation while swiping to the left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to handle swiping event inside the cell in order to set alpha value of delete button increasing gradually.

I would like to have like this:

[image: while swiping]

[image: end swiping]

As It is seen in the image, while swiping the cell through the left side, editing buttons' alpha increases. And finally It is set to 1.0. 
How can I implement increasing alpha on swiping using default red delete button?
Note: I have followed the [Bradens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159476/uitableviewcelldeleteconfirmationcontrol-issue) to handle delete button inside the cell in iOS 6/7.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell/blob/master/SWTableViewCell/ViewController.m), and try to change the alpha value when user is swiping.

```
- (NSArray *)rightButtons
{
    NSMutableArray *rightUtilityButtons = [NSMutableArray new];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
    [UIColor colorWithRed:0.78f green:0.78f blue:0.8f alpha:1.0]
                                            title:@"More"];
    [rightUtilityButtons sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor:
    [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.231f blue:0.188 alpha:1.0f]
                                            title:@"Delete"];

    return rightUtilityButtons;
}
```

my guess would be to set and reset alpha from

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell scrollingToState:(SWCellState)state
```

P.S,  i did not try this library before.